# How to replace or alter function WebForm_OnSubmit()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

My web form uses asp:CustomValidator validation so ASP.NET writes out `<form method="post" action="./MyPropertiesEnquiry.aspx?rwndrnd=0.30325462348842547" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1">` and also

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;
return true;
}
```

I need to send a hit event to Google Analytics only if validation has succeeded so I presume I need to insert my code just before `return true;`.

I have seen an almost solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361910/is-there-any-native-way-in-asp-net-to-do-a-success-message)

but the inserted code is in the wrong place for me (it's at the start of the WebForm_OnSubmit() ).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add your CustomCode() here:

```
<form id="your_form_id" runat="server" onsubmit="CustomCode();">
```

after that, your WebForm_OnSubmit() will automatically looks like:

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit()
{
    if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false)
        return false;CustomCode();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a Javascript function override as it seems the simplest technique AND it has the huge advantage of being able to place custom code precisely.

```
WebForm_OnSubmit = function () {
if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;

// Custom code here...

return true;
}
```

I tested it on my website and I was able to send data to Google Analytics just I had hoped.